# How to use a string as a variable?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a function that will change the text of a Tkinter widget based on the state of the widget and the widget itself. In this function, I also need to change the value of the state that we take in as a variable to change it later on and so it will work for not just one scenario. This is what I have so far and it is not working because when I globalize the variable it is saying it is parameter and as a global. I know this is pretty basic stuff and I know this doesn't work but I am wondering if there is a way to work around this thanks!

```
from tkinter import*
from definitions import*

root = Tk()
root.title("Chemistry Tool")
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')

#### MODLE (Data,Methods) ####
state_1 = 0


def drop_down(state, state_var, button):
    global setattr(state_var)
    if state == 0:
        button.config(text="↓")
        state_var = 1
    else:
        button.config(text="→")
        state_var = 0



#### Controlers (Widgets that change data) ####
drop1 = Button(root, text="→", bg="WHITE", command= lambda: drop_down(state_1, "state_1", drop1))
drop1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)

#### VIEW (Widgets that display outputs) ####
display = Text(root, bg="WHITE")
display.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=SE)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

```
  File "D:/Devlopment/Python/AP-Computer-Science-Project-1/main.py", line 13
    global setattr(state_var)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you can't use `setattr` or `global` like that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr -> `setattr` should set a new property on an existing object

Comment: Yes I understand that but I am wondering how I could work around this?

Comment: The error doesn't match your code.

Comment: If your object is already global, just `setattr(object, name, value)`. But one question. Is this your `main.py` file?

Comment: Yes this is my main.py file, also in my senario what would be my object, name, and value? I'm pretty sure that my name would be ```state_var``` but I am not sure about the other ones?

Comment: Removing `setattr` should work, but in general I try to avoid using global variables in functions anyway

Comment: I think I found a better way, I can just take in the widget I am trying to change, get the text from that and check what it is and change it based off of that insteadof using the state method I was trying to use. Sorry for wasting you alls time.

Answer (score 0):

I just am not basing my changes off of the actual value of the text instead of the system I was using with a variable called `state` above.

```
from tkinter import*
from definitions import*

root = Tk()
root.title("Chemistry Tool")
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')

#### MODLE (Data,Methods) ####


def drop_down(button):
    if button['text'] == "→":
        button.config(text="↓")
    elif button['text'] == "↓":
        button.config(text="→")
        state_var = 0
    print(button['text'])



#### Controlers (Widgets that change data) ####
drop1 = Button(root, text="→", bg="WHITE", width=2, command= lambda: drop_down(drop1))
drop1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)

#### VIEW (Widgets that display outputs) ####
display = Text(root, bg="WHITE")
display.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=SE)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is this an answer? If not, you need to delete it. The answer section is strictly for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the state of elements in a dict and pass the key for that dict:

```
from tkinter import*
from definitions import*

root = Tk()
root.title("Chemistry Tool")
root.iconbitmap('favicon.ico')

#### MODLE (Data,Methods) ####
state_1 = 0

states = {"state_1" : 0}

def drop_down(state_var, button):
    if states[state_var] == 0:
        button.config(text="↓")
        states[state_var] = 1
    else:
        button.config(text="→")
        states[state_var] = 0



#### Controlers (Widgets that change data) ####
drop1 = Button(root, text="→", bg="WHITE", command= lambda: drop_down("state_1", drop1))
drop1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N)

#### VIEW (Widgets that display outputs) ####
display = Text(root, bg="WHITE")
display.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, sticky=SE)

root.mainloop()
```